# capistrano 3 how to run a runner command after deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

Trying to do something like:

```
task :refresh_leads do
    "bundle exec runner 'Leads.refresh'"
end

after :deploy, "runner refresh_leads"
```

This returns success but it doesn't actually run.  Can someone point me to an exemplar of a runner task after deploy?

Answer (score 3):

Try This :

```
namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Refresh Leads'
  task :refresh_leads do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      runner "Leads.refresh"
    end
  end
end

# The above restart task is not run by default
# Uncomment the following line to run it on deploys if needed
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:refresh_leads'
```

Comment: I get `undefined method runner for #<SSHKit::Backend::Netssh:0x00007f8f4bae7540>`

Comment: @RobertPankowecki I had the same issue, so I changed it to this:

execute :bundle, :exec, :rails, :runner, "Leads.refresh"